# The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.(issue when building release apk)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

compileSdkVersion 28
Hello friends!
I am developing an App, when compiling everything is fine. but I have been curious to take the release APK but for this I execute the command flutter build apk --release everything is fine but in the end it gives me some warnings and an error.

[  +23 ms] The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve

The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.

Comment: anyone solve this issue by chance?